# AJAX hook sequence

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

In my theme's functions.php, I'm including a signup.php file which I want to use for all the signup setup and AJAX calls.

This file will be included at 'template_redirect'.

When I try to evoke an AJAX call, nothing happens. But instead, if I put the code directly into the functions.php file, everything works great.

So I'm assung that the action 'wp_ajax_...' is executed before 'template_redirect'. Is that right?
[This great article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162862/how-to-get-wordpress-hook-run-sequence) isn't too helpful for AJAX requests, as it's not clear which one was proceeded first.

Comment: I think an ajax call will not load the whole wp environment, because an ajax call don't need allt those things like e.g. template engine and other front end things. So it can be that `template_redirect` do not executet in ajax calls.

Comment: you are right @AndyTschiersch. I did some research and testing: the only available hooks in an wp_ajax_{action} function are 'admin_init', 'wp_loaded' and all previous one.

It took me a while to finally understand how a WP website is builded, but that issue taught me a lot.